# how to get disk details(vendor name, capacity, etc.) programmatically in C in Linux

Tags: linux, hardware, disk

I want to write a simple C program to dump the detailed information about disks currently installed in my computer.

There are chucks of command line tools suit to my need, such as `hdparm -i /dev/sda`, `lshw -class disk` or `hwinfo --disk`. However, I don't want to implement this simple task(if it is simple) via `popen()` or such, instead `ioctl()`, `proc fs` or `sysfs` are more preferable ways.

Using `strace` to inspect the system call of `hdparm -i /dev/sda`, I hardly find any useful clues. I don't know how and where these commands obtain information.